# dropdown onchange event not working

Tags: jquery, html

my dropdown list event `onchange` doesn't work in server while it works fine on my localhost. I'm using jquery. what would be the reason.

html:

```
<select name="cities" id="cities" onchange="change_city();">
<option value="Basel" selected="selected">Basel</option>
<option value="Bern">Bern</option>
<option value="Fribourg">Fribourg</option>
<option value="Geneva">Geneva</option>
<option value="Lugano">Lugano</option>
<option value="Zurich">Zurich</option>

</select>
```

jQuery:

```
function change_city(){
    var home_city =$("#cities option:selected").val();
    $.cookie("home_city", home_city, { expires: 3650, path: '/' });
    location.reload( true );

}
```

Comment: Do you mean the `change` event isn't firing at all? Or is it hitting `change_city()` but not reloading the page?

Comment: i found that change event is firing but page is not reloaded. i have used jquery.cookie to set cookie. i have to put cookie after taking the value from dropdown.

Comment: At what point does it fail? Do you definitely have a reference to jQuery on the release version?

Comment: I think it was having some issue with IE, but working fine in Mozilla Firefox. Can you check that?

Comment: @town: thanks for your time. i solved it. my jquery.min.js was not uploaded correctely. i uploaded it again and every thing is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```
<select name="cities" id="cities">
<option value="Basel" selected="selected">Basel</option>
<option value="Bern">Bern</option>
<option value="Fribourg">Fribourg</option>
<option value="Geneva">Geneva</option>
<option value="Lugano">Lugano</option>
<option value="Zurich">Zurich</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#cities').change(function(){
    var home_city =$("#cities option:selected").val();
    console.log(home_city);
    $.cookie("home_city", home_city, { expires: 3650, path: '/' });
    location.reload( true );

});
```